# Using pythontex in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I can't for the life of me figure out how to compile or even format a tex file using pythontex in the Latex workshop extension for vscode. Would someone be able to share a working example, a good tutorial, or suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

In the `settings.json` of your VSCode, paste the following to add `pythontex` in the `tools` section:

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    ... some code ...
    {
        "name": "pythontex",
        "command": "pythontex",
        "args": [
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    },
    ... some code ...
]
```

Then add this to the `recipes` section:

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    ... some code ...
    {
        "name": "compile with pythontex enabled",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex",
            "pythontex",
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    },
    ... some code ...
]
```

(Optionally, substitute `pdflatex` with a compiler of your choice.)

`pythontex` needs a three-step compiling process which involves calling `pdflatex`, then `pythontex`, then again `pdflatex`. You need to configure this as a `recipe` (as shown above) for the package-specific code to work.